# Welche Bedeutung hat in diesem Kontext "kaltmachen"?

Tags: meaning

Es gibt das [Kinderlied "Die Affen rasen durch den Wald"](https://www.sternschnuppe-kinderlieder.de/kinderlieder-texte/244/Wer-hat-die-Kokosnuss-geklaut) und dort gibt es die Zeile "Der eine macht den anderen kalt". Nun finde ich das etwas brutal obwohl es sich wunderbar reimt. Hat hier "kalt machen" noch eine andere Bedeutung als "umbringen" oder "töten"? Bei [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/kaltmachen) gibt es darauf zumindest keinen Hinweis.

Comment: Klappe zu - Affe tot. Ich glaube es gibt da keine andere Bedeutung.

Comment: Eine Suche bei "Google Books" zeigt, dass sich in veschiedenen Texten genau darüber echauffiert wird. Es wird dargelegt, dass dieser Zeile selten Beachtung geschenkt wird.

Comment: "Klappe zu - Affe tot" ist auch noch mal eine gute Assoziation, thx.

Comment: Es gibt schon noch andere Bedeutungen von [kaltmachen](https://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/kalt%20machen.php). Allerdings passt im Kontext des Liedes nur "umbringen". Man sollte das aber nicht überbewerten, der einzige Grund für die Verwendung ist der Reim. Ich glaube, dass auch Kinder verstehen, dass das Umbringen nicht wörtlich zu nehmen ist.

Comment: @PaulFrost Ich würde da widersprechen. Kaltmachen hat im Gegensatz zu heiß/kalt machen doch eine andere Bedeutung, oder nicht? Auch glaube ich nicht, dass der einzige Grund der Reim ist..

Comment: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kaltmachen und https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kaltmachen

Comment: @choXer Gute Frage, ob "kaltmachen" und "kalt machen" diesselbe Bedeutung haben. Im Sinne von "umbringen" würde ich es auch als "kaltmachen" schreiben. In (konjugierter) Präsensform ist ein evtl. Unterschied jedenfalls nicht sichtbar ("macht den andern kalt"). Fakt ist: Es gibt andere Bedeutungen, aber sie passen hier nicht. Und welchen anderen Grund als den Reim schlägst Du vor?

Comment: @PaulFrost: Das Problem mit der Reimthese ist, das wir nicht wissen, wer zuerst da war, der Wald oder das Kalt. Und was heißt "nicht wörtlich nehmen" bei bildhafter Sprache - es würde bedeuten, sie töten sich schon gegenseitig, aber werden danach nicht wirklich kalt - eine merkwürdige These! Und wieso soll man es nicht als töten verstehen, wenn man, wie ich unterstelle, vermutet, dass Du es eigentlich meinst? Es ist ein Kinderlied, kein Tatsachenbericht. "Hoppe, hoppe, Reiter, wenn er fällt, dann schreit er, fällt er in den Graben, fresse ihn die Raben ...".

Comment: @userunknown In der Beurteilung werden wir uns vermutlich nicht einig werden. Mich interessiert aber Deine persönliche These, warum der Text "der eine macht den andern kalt" verwendet wird. Um im wörtlichen Sinne zu sagen, dass es im Streit um eine verschwundene Kokosnuss Tote gibt?

Comment: ... weil deutsche lieder und märchen ja sonst so friedlich sind :P

Comment: @PaulFrost: Ja natürlich, was sonst? Es ist ein Kinderlied und nicht ernsthaft und kein Tatsachenbericht. Bei Hänsel & Gretel will die Hexe die Kinder fressen und wird von diesen in den Ofen gestoßen, wo sie verbrennt. Das Genre ist klar und drastisch aber nicht real.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich glaube nicht, dass eine andere Deutung möglich ist als die naheliegende. Die Brutalität verstehe ich als Übertreibung, die ausdrücken soll, dass alle Affen extrem wütend sind.

Das Lied entstand kurz nach den zweiten Weltkrieg in einer Gesellschaft, die gerade aus dem Krieg kam. Die brutale, tabulose Sprache dieses Strophe machte damals für <strike>Jugendliche</strike> Halbstarke vermutlich einen guten Teil das Reizes dieses Gröl-Liedes aus.

Comment: + 1 für Halbstarke ;)

Comment: Dann gibt es wohl nur die naheliegende Bedeutung. So werde ich es meinem 2-Jährigen dann auch erklären, wenn er fragt, was das wohl bedeutet. :D

Comment: Die bei Wikipedia genannten "erstmals in den 1950er Jahren in Liederbüchern konfessionsgebundender Jugendgruppen" und Halbstarke dürfen weitgehend disjunkte Mengen sein.

Comment: "Die für Lieder ungewohnt brutale, tabulose Sprache" - ähem ... "die Hexe musste braten, die Kinder geh'n nach Haus", "schießt auf dich den Schrot (...) und dann bist du tot", "fällt er in den Graben, fressen ihn die Raben" uvm. ... nein, ich würde nicht sagen, dass dieses Lied besonders heraussticht.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Dem kann nur zustimmen. Der Liedtext liegt m.E. auf dem Niveau des Spruchs "[Brecht dem Schütz die Gräten, alle Macht den Räten](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/berlin/und-das-ist-gut-so/752752.html)". Ich will mal hoffen, dass die 68-er das nicht wörtlich gemeint haben. Aber vielleicht haben sie sich  vom Kokusnuss-Lied inspirieren lassen ;-)  Und vielleicht war ja der eine oder andere Sponti früher in einer konfessionsgebundenden Jugendgruppe?

Comment: @O.R. Mapper: Na schön, ich hänge absolut nicht an dieser Behauptung. Es war auch nicht so gemeint, dass es nicht auch andere Lieder mit brutaler Sprache gab. Ich habe es editiert. 
user unknown: das sehe ich anders, "Halbstarke" wurde nicht nur im engeren Sinn für Mopedgangs oder Vandalen benutzt, sondern auch in einem weiteren Sinn herablassend für alle möglichen Jugendlichen, deren Verhalten Erwachsenen irgendwie nicht gefiel. Der Wikipedia-Artikel ist m.E. widersprüchlich, die weiter unten genannten Liederbücher wie die "Mundorgel" sind nicht konfessionsgebunden.

Comment: @HalvarF: Da steht nach meiner Erinnerung "erstmals" bei den konfessionsgebundenen Jugendgruppen. Und Jugendliche haben schon immer Verhalten gezeigt, das Erwachsenen nicht gefällt -  also passt nach Deiner Ansicht der Begriff "Halbstarke" für alle und wäre damit aller Trennschärfe verlustig. Wenn Du "Jugendliche" durchstreichst, und stattdessen "Halbstarke" setzt, wirkt es aber so, als drücke der Begriff "Halbstarke" den Sachverhalt besser aus; meines Erachtens ist er deutlich schlechter. Halbstarke hörten damals Rock 'n' Roll, natürlich nicht ausschließlich und exklusiv, aber bitte.

Comment: Ich denke auch, dass die Konfessionsgebundenheit relativ irrelevant ist. Zumal es von den lokalen Gegebenheiten abhängt, welche Art von Jugendorganisationen überhaupt zur Auswahl stehen. Diese Art von Liedgut zieht sich durch alle Organisationen, die in irgendeiner Nachfolge zu den frühen Jugendbewegunen stehen, von den Pfadfindern über die Jungschar bis zu den Rote Falken. Ich erinnere nur an das eine Lied über einen gewissen Aufstand auf Kuba... Aber genauso an den "Lagerboogie".