# Drastische Wortwahl (Tod und Gewalt) nur des Reimes wegen?

Tags: word-usage, rhetoric

Meine Frage ist durch [Welche Bedeutung hat in diesem Kontext "kaltmachen"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/61944/34192) motiviert. Das Kinderlied "Die Affen rasen durch den Wald" (auch bekannt unter dem Refrain "Wer hat die Kokosnuss geklaut?") beginnt mit

> Die Affen rasen durch den Wald, der eine macht den andern kalt

Es besteht Einigkeit darüber, dass in diesem Kontext *kaltmachen* nichts anderes als *umbringen* bzw. *töten* bedeutet. Es bleibt aber die Frage, warum diese drastische Formulierung für die zweite Liedzeile gewählt wurde. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Affen_rasen_durch_den_Wald) sagt dazu u.a.

> Gottfried Küntzel bezeichnet das Lied als einen „zum Grölen tendierenden Hordengesang“, nach Tobias Widmaier ist die Tatsache, dass es nicht schön gesungen werden müsse, der maßgebliche Grund für seine Beliebtheit. Als weiterer Grund wird angeführt, dass die Liedzeile „der eine macht den andern kalt“ den sozialen Normen entgegenstehe und das Lied dadurch „einen gewissen Kitzel“ biete. In manchen Versionen ist dem Lied eine Schlussstrophe angehängt, die hierzu mit „Und die Moral von der Geschicht: Klaut keine Kokosnüsse nicht“ einen Ausgleich schaffen soll.

Aus meiner Sicht gibt es folgende Thesen zur äffischen "Tötungsorgie":

1. Es ist ein beabsichtiger Verstoß gegen soziale (und ich ergänze: ethische) Normen, um das Lied interessant zu machen.
2. Die jugendlichen Sänger sollen am Ende des Liedes erkennen, dass ein geringfügiger Anlass zu Wut, Hass und letztlich zu einer Tötungsorgie führen kann - also ein moralisches Lehrstück.
3. Es gibt keinen tieferen Grund, es wurde lediglich ein Reim zu "Wald" gesucht.

Ich neige These 3 zu, möchte aber wissen, ob es noch weitere Erklärungen gibt.

Ähnlich gelagerte Beispiele sind  m.E. die Sprüche

> [Brecht dem Schütz die Gräten, alle Macht den Räten](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/berlin/und-das-ist-gut-so/752752.html).

Klaus Schütz war zwischen 1967 und 1977 Regierender Bürgermeister in Berlin. "Die Gräten brechen"  bedeutet "die Knochen brechen", man könnte das also als Aufforderung zu einer Körperverletzung sehen. Ich will aber hoffen, dass das von den 68-ern nicht wörtlich gemeint war, sondern wieder nur zum Zweck des Reims verwendet wurde (und natürlich, um dem Staat den Kampf anzusagen).

> [Sport ist Mord](https://www.gesundheit.de/wissen/haetten-sie-es-gewusst/wahrheiten-und-irrtuemer/sport-ist-mord-stimmt-das).

Auch hier ist m.E. der Reim ausschlaggebend. Vielleicht hat Sport auch Gefahren für die Gesundheit, und vielleicht ist sogar mal jemand um Leben dabei gekommen, aber "Mord" kann nicht ernst gemeint sein.

Meine Frage: Gibt es möglicherweise allgemein verwendete rhetorische Figuren, die mit einer drastischen Wortwahl Aufmerksamkeit wecken wollen?

Comment: Was meinen Sie mit dem Wort "Figuren" in Ihrer Frage?

Comment: @avgJoe Vgl. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorisches_Stilmittel; in English " figures of speech".

Comment: Obwohl Hyperbel (https://wortwuchs.net/stilmittel/hyperbel/) als Antwort passt, wäre es interessant zu wissen ob es eine spezifischere Terminologie für den oben beschriebenen Fall gäbe.

Comment: Es gibt jede These, die jemand in den Raum stellt, wie absurd sie auch sein möge. Sei es, dass man Affen mit ethische Normen zu kommen versucht, sei es, dass man jugendliche Sänger vorstellt, die willenlos Texte vortragen und dann durch ihren eigenen Gesang moralisch belehrt werden. Wer solch bizarre Thesen aufstellt sollte vielleicht besser seine Prämissen überprüfen.

Comment: Ich verstehe deine Beispiele nicht so richtig. Bei allen ist es doch gerade wichtig, dass *Mord* oder *Gräten* der Reim ist, um den Sinn zu formen. "Sport ist ein Wort" oder "Unkraut jäten - Alle Macht den Räten" steht ja in keinem Zusammenhang zur Aussage.

Comment: Da kommen wir die Worte der Cartoonfigur Droopy Dog in der deutschen Synchronisation in den Sinn: "Mein Name ist Drops - wer mich ärgert, geht hops! / Nur des Reimes wegen, ich bitte sich nicht aufzuregen."

Comment: Die Figuren selbst wollen gar nichts wecken, sie sind ein Mittel. Umformuliert müsste die Frage also lauten: "Gibt es rhet. Fig., mit denen man Aufmerksamkeit wecken kann?" und die Antwort wäre "drastische Wortwahl". Da Du im verqueren Satzbau die Antwort selbst gibt bzw. weitreichende Unterstellungen nutzt ist die Frage sinnlos bzw. nicht beantwortbar.  Wer drastische Ausdrücke verwenden will, um sein Ziel zu erreichen, der hat die Auswahl ja schon getroffen, und Du hast deren Charakteristik schon benannt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bei allen drei Beispielen kann man von der rhetorischen Figur der [*Übertreibung*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbel_(Sprache)) sprechen.

Comment: Vielen Dank (+1). Nicht ganz so hyperbolisch wäre z.B. "Schütz, nimm Dich in Acht, die Räte kommen an die Macht" gewesen. Das reimt sich auch, klingt aber nicht so dramatisch. Daher also nicht nur der Reim!

Comment: Nicht jede Übertreibung ist drastisch, die Frage dreht sich aber spezifisch um das Drastische.